# C++ -- линковка статических библиотек на linux в CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, glut

На Windows в Visual Studio было достаточно раскидать файлы по специальным папкам и прописать:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glut32.lib")
```

Как же быть на линуксе? Вот из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685206/pragma-commentlib-xxx-lib-equivalent-under-linux) ответа я понял, что `#pragma comment` не сработает. Еще я понял, что в `CMakeLists.txt` надо все линковки самому прописывать. Я поставил `freeglut3-dev` и что откуда мне линковать?

Вот мой `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(paintc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp" "*.h")
add_executable(paintc ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: `FIND_PACKAGE` вам в помощь, видимо. Ну и видимо библиотеки по другому называться будут (судя по всему: [freeglut3-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/freeglut3-dev) [список файлов](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/freeglut3-dev/filelist))

Comment: Пример (для динамической библиотеки libexiv2 из пакета libexiv2-dev): `find_package(Exiv2) include_directories( ${EXIV2_INCLUDE_DIR}) target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXIV2_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: По каким специальным папкам? Зачем pragma? В VS надо указывать аргументы компиляции, задающие пути к папкам с бибилиотеками и сами библиотеки для линковки. На линуксе так же.

Comment: @VTT C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503, в ней bin, lib и include. Вот эти специальные папки. И в VS они по умолчанию указаны, так что не надо ничего дописывать. Что на линуксе делать то?

Comment: @Eevee я ж вам написал. Найти (с помощью FIND_PACKAGE) требуемый пакет, и прописать найденные заголовочные файлы и библиотеки

Comment: Вообще-то в эти папки нельзя ничего добавлять. Да это и невозможно без повышения привилегий.

Answer (score 2):

Все оказалось намного интереснее. Оказывается, при компиляции на `gcc` надо передавать параметры (не файлы), указывающие на линковки. В CMake для этого используется `target_link_libraries(<имя проекта> <имена включений разделенные пробелами и без буквы l вначале>)`. В моем случае это будет выглядеть так: `target_link_libraries(paintc glut GLU GL)`. При вызове `gcc` же необходимо будет указать `-lglut -lGLU -lGL`.

Comment: если что, то ты почти наверняка линкуешь динамические библиотеки, а не статические...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Хорошо, приму к сведению. Спасибо.

Comment: Зачем вызывать `gcc`, снова указывая флаги? CMake генерирует Makefile, в котором уже всё настроено. В этом смысл системы сборки. К тому же `target_link_libraries` принимает не такие параметры

Comment: Да никто и не вызывает `gcc`. Я его приплел для примера, если кто то будет гуглить эту же проблему. А что насчет параметров `target_link_libraries`, то с такими параметрами у меня все заработало.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(<имя проекта> <имена включений разделенные пробелами и без буквы l вначале>)` - не имя проекта, а имя исполняемого файла или библиотеки (цели/target), которую вы создаёте с помощью `add_executable` или `add_library`. И вот если в качестве первого параметра `add_executable` или `add_library` вы указали `${PROJECT_NAME}` - вот тогда да, тогда - имя проекта